# Implementation of mergesort in Java

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I'd like to know if the following code is a good implementation of MergeSort? I tried some examples and the code was right, so I guess that the algorithm works correctly.

```
public static int[] myMerge (int[] array, int[] array2){

    int[] giveback = new int[array.length + array2.length];
    int i = 0; 
    int j = 0; 


    for (int x = 0; x < giveback.length; x++){

        if (array[i] >= array2[j]){

            giveback[x] = array2[j];
            j++;

        }
        else{

            giveback[x] = array[i];
            i++;
        }

        if (i == array.length){

            x++;
            for(int c = j; c < array2.length; c++){


                giveback[x] = array2[c];
                x++;    
            }

            return giveback;
        }

        if (j == array2.length){

            x++;
            for (int b = i; b < array.length; b++){

                giveback[x] = array[b];
                x++;
            }
            return giveback;
        }


    }       
    return giveback;
}

public static int[] myMergeSort (int[] array){

    if (array.length <= 1 ){

        return array;
    }

    if (array.length % 2 == 0){

        int[] right = new int[array.length/2];
        int[] left = new int[array.length/2];
        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++){

            left[i] = array[i];

        }

        for (int j = array.length/2; j < array.length; j++){

            right[counter] = array[j];
            counter++;

        }
        return myMerge(myMergeSort(right),myMergeSort(left));
    }
    else{

        int[] right = new int[array.length/2];
        int[] left = new int[array.length/2];
        int counter2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length/2 +1; i++){

            left[i] = array[i];
        }

        for(int j = array.length/2 +1; j < array.length; j++){

            right[counter2]=array[j];
            counter2++;
        }
        return myMerge(myMergeSort(right),myMergeSort(left));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to distinguish if `array.length` if even or odd.
Just do:

```
    int[] right = new int[array.length/2];
    int[] left = new int[array.length - array.length/2];
```

It will make the two tables to have exactly `array.length` items together, divided by half as precisely as possible.